# These lines are a bit strange to me. What do they mean?

Tags: ksh

I've learned BASH before but this is the first time trying to work with KSH. I was given the code below from my instructor and it does not seem to be similar to BASH when looking at line 2, 4 to 10, 11, 12. I know that `<<END` is the here document, but why does it have to be paired with the `cat` command?. Also, the `run_query` command does not seem right as I tried looking it up and found nothing. Please give me some insight. Thanks.

```
1 /usr/ksh_env
2 export PATH=./lib     
3 
4 my_test=$(cat <<END
5 CREATE TABLE customers (
6  id int(5) not null auto_increment,
7  fname varchar(40) not null,
8...
9...
10 ) END)
11 run_query "$my_test"
12 run_query "delete from my_test auto_increment = 0"
```

Comment: run_query might be another bash script or some executable that executes the SQL command that's specified in the argument. The script creates a SQL table named customers. Line 12 empties the data table, in case it is not empty. This script looks like an installation script that "resets" your database to its initial state.

Comment: Thanks for your input Schien. what about line 1, 2? I read somewhere line 2 export the library of some sort. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Line 10 is wrong. The ending word of a here-document must be the only characters on the line. In line 10, the first close parenthesis belongs to the SQL statement, then there's the here-doc word, then the close parenthesis for the command substitution. Each of those 3 things needs to be on a separate line.

Comment: Online man pages for ksh can be found at http://www.kornshell.com/doc/

Comment: Line 1 and 2 are just setting up dependencies and path.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks. I typed it wrong by accident.